# Set up MySQL slave to slave replication

Tags: linux, mysql, rsync

I have two machines with MySQL servers instances A and B. I want to add another MySQL server C which should replicate from B rather than from A. I may stop B but not A. These are the steps I tried:

1. Create a new VM for server C
2. `rsync /var/lib/mysql` from B to C
3. Stop B
4. `rsync /var/lib/mysql` from B to C again.
5. Start B (ok)
6. Start C with `skip-slave-start`
7. Take a look at `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` on server C.
8. `CHANGE MASTER` on server C
9. `START SLAVE` on server C
10. Failed.

    ```
    Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Could not find first log file name in binary log index file'
    ```

Which values should I set on `CHANGE MASTER`?

Answer (score 1):

I found out the answer on my own. After the first rsync (before stopping the MySQL daemon), you need to stop the slave process on server B and ask its master status with `SHOW MASTER STATUS`. These values must be set with `CHANGE MASTER` on server C before starting the slave process there.